# How to pass parameter to maven test

Tags: maven, unit-testing, testing, junit, automated-tests

I have One test suite running in two environment.
Sometimes, I would like to run tests in localhost:8080 and sometimes at localhost:8585.
Jenkins run the tests by "`mvn test`" command.

How could I pass the port by parameter? Something like "mvn test 8080".

Comment: I forgot a detail. I have to use the port in my junit code: driver.get("http://localhost:8080");

Answer (score 5):

I add a plugin on maven pom.xml

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
          <property>
             <name>fileName</name>
             <value>${fileName}</value>
          </property>
        </systemProperties>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And get the parameter in junit code with

```
String fileName = System.getProperty("fileName");
```

After, I run my tests with -DfileName argument

```
mvn clean test -DfileName="config-test.xml"
```

Now, I can put all configurations in xml file and load appropriate file with the corrects parameters.

```
mvn clean test -DfileName="config-test.xml"
```

or

```
mvn clean test -DfileName="config-homolog.xml"
```

I solved the problem with the tips from Sandra Sukarieh and http://syntx.io/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-junit-tests-from-the-maven-surefire-plugin/

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
mvn -Dtest=testName -Dargline="-Dport=portValue"
```

and portValue will be either 8080 or 8585, and while you have a "port" variable declared in your test code.

Comment: I have a variable "public String port;" and I execute "mvn test -Dtest=RegrasAutoriaLBTest -Dargline="-Dport=8080". But System.out.println(port) = null

Comment: try making port an integer not a string

Comment: @SandraSukarieh , I am using your approach for string type parameters. But it is not successfully passing parameters to my test class.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, I found the below code:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <configuration>
        <systemProperties>
          <property>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>${testsuite}</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
          </property>
        </systemProperties>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Please run the maven command:

```
mvn test -Dtestsuite =yourxmlsuitepath
```