# Java pass arguments dynamically to a junit test

Tags: java, junit

I'm doing a special junit test, that the params are introduced in the front-end of the application by the user and received in back-end of the application. And i want to generate junit test that use that information as parameters.

I saw some guide (like mykong guide and tutorial points) but most of them use static parametrized and i want some dynamic thing. I already tried to use junit annotations, do a set or pass the params to the junit class, use mockito methods but nothings work as dynamic process

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Right now i have something like that

```
public void run (Object foo)  //Class that contains the information introduced by the user
JUnitCore junit1 = new JUnitCore();
Result result4 = JUnitCore.runClasses(GeneratedTest.getClass()); //Junit class

 //I tried: do a setFoo on the GeneratedTest ; pass the foo on the constructor; 

for (Failure failure : result4.getFailures()) {
                    System.out.println(failure.toString());
}
```

Comment: Dynamic tests can be constructed with "Test Factories" - https://dzone.com/articles/junit-5-dynamic-tests-generate-tests-at-run-time

Comment: The behaviour you are searching for is not what a unit test is intended for

Comment: I'm also thinking that you might misuse unit tests for a wrong purpose. Can you explain us your exact use case?

Comment: You want to have integration tests - end-to-end. It's a task for jmeter. In unit-tests you are supposed to test particular components. Say, you check that front-end respects all the settings and doesn't have hard code - outputs on the URL expected data, makes expected requests to BE. Then you check that back-end reacts on the requests and responds properly.
When I read your question I also thougth about ReflectionUtils to inject classes.

Comment: You could set up a special framework like [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io) 
or just provide your testing code as normal endpoints (you can still use assertions to make the code 'test-like').

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the nicest solution, but maybe an acceptable workaround:

- generate your unit test so that it fetches parameters from System properties
- run the generated JUnit test in its own JVM, and pass the parameters/properties on the command line

Comment: This is how it would be done in an automated environment with maven: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120909/how-to-pass-parameter-to-maven-test