# How can I verify that my MAVEN_OPTS environment variable is being passed to the java process being started?

Tags: java, maven

I'm setting some options -Dmyflag=myvalue in MAVEN_OPTS.  I know this works based on other testing I've done (when using [mvn spring-boot:run](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html#using-boot-running-with-the-maven-plugin) ) but a newly set value I'm using doesn't seem to be working.

The first place to start is to make sure the option is being passed to the program being started by maven.  In my case, I'm running a unit test that dsdsneeds some options set on the command line.

**Is there a maven command that will show me the -Doptions that are being passed to the java commands that are started by Maven?**

*NOTE: This may be an issue with the surefire plugin not passing MAVEN_OPTS when starting tests.*

I've tried

```
mvn -X clean install
```

and I see output that implies that a test is being started, the output is something like:

```
Forking command line: /bin/sh -c cd /my/proj && /usr/bin/java -jar /.../my.jar
```

And I don't see any options being passed so I'm guessing that the MAVEN_OPTS are not being passed to the unit test that is running.

Searching for answers I found these links:

- [How to pass parameter to maven test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120909/how-to-pass-parameter-to-maven-test)
- [Passing properties to surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) (Not on StackOverflow).
- [Passing command line arguments to surefire plugin](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Passing-command-line-arguments-to-surefire-plugin-td2263928.html)  (Not on StackOverflow).

Comment: You can use `jps -mlvV` to print all running Java processes and the commands that were used to start them. If you can find your Java process in the list, you'll be able to see arguments that it was run with, then just verify if it has arguments that you set in `MAVEN_OPTS`

Answer (score 2):

From `mvn --help`:

> -D,--define                       Define a system property

So anything you pass in with `-D`, you should be able to read back with `System.getProperty("<arg>")`.

Alternatively, you can use `mvn -X ...` to see what is being passed:

> -X,--debug                             Produce execution debug output

As for your comment:

> This may be an issue with the surefire plugin not passing MAVEN_OPTS when starting tests.

When tests are run - either with surefire or failsafe - they are run in a separate thread; from [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html#Forked_Test_Execution):

> The *default setting* is `forkCount=1`/`reuseForks=true`, which means that maven-surefire-plugin creates one new JVM process to execute all tests in one Maven module.

This new thread **does not** receive any properties from MAVEN_OPTS. However, it **will** receive properties passed on the command line with -D...

Comment: This definately helped me because I could use the command `mvn clean install $MAVEN_OPTS` and the test worked.  But my question was how can I see that the MAVEN_OPTS have been passed, and this doesn't answer that question.  Can you add a statement that says: To see the java command line being run by maven use the -X option `mvn -X clean install` as you mentioned in your question.  That is the correct way, but the surefire plugin doesn't just pass them on the command line as you might expect, I'd have to research this more and that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Very good. Upvoted. "they are run in a separate thread" is the exact point. If you can, could you add the doc reference about this? Because I was testing, and this behavior is not just for "surefire" or "failsafe". It is for every plugin installed outside the default maven lifecycle. I guess...

Comment: @rios0rios0 added